# Case insensitive search in a text file

Tags: c#, case-insensitive

I need a case insensitive search for the following code...

```
  while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
     if (line.Contains(line2))
     dest.WriteLine("LineNo : " + counter.ToString() + " : " + line);
     counter++;
    }
```

I have tried like this

```
if (line.Contains(line2,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

But it doesnt seem fit..Any suggestion??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

Forget my first answer, I misread the question.

You should use [String.IndexOf (String, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx):

```
foreach (String Row in File.ReadLines("Test.txt"))
{
    if (Row.IndexOf("asd", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
    {
        // The row contains the string.
    }
}
```

Comment: That will only match when `line2` occurs at the beginning of `line`.  Doesn't solve the problem at all.

Comment: Your example does NOT work.  Consider how the original code behaves on `line = "abcdef"; line2 = "de";` and how your "fix" behaves.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yes, I misread the question, I changed the code accordingly.

Comment: A `0` result from `IndexOf` also means the string was found.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to create a string extension method:

```
if (line.ContainsCaseInsensitive(value))
{
    // ..
}

public static bool ContainsCaseInsensitive(this string source, string find)
{
    return source.IndexOf(find, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In user-contributed comments on the [`String.Contains` documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx), a workaround is provided.

```
bool contains = str1.IndexOf(str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try StringComparer.[CurrentCultureIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression (Regex class in .NET) and specify case insensitivity option (part of the constructor).

Comment: Counter-intuitively, if `line2` is fairly long, this can be MUCH faster than `string.Contains`.  However, you need to be careful if `line2` could possibly contain special characters that need to be escaped.

Answer (score -3):

You can convert both sides to upper or lower case using `"myString".ToLower();`

It's effectively case-insensitive.

Comment: @rmx i have two text files..one text file has patterns and other has filelist..i need to check the patterns with filelist and log into another file..so i have to check  case-insensitively

Comment: This would create two new instances of a String, which is way slower and not as effectife as StringComparer.

Comment: True, this is the best answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257114/case-insensitive-search-in-a-text-file/4257176#4257176

Comment: In many alphabets, but not all.  For more information, read [Larry Osterman's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/07/01/171078.aspx)

Comment: @Ben: you can specify a `CultureInfo` as an argument. But like I said, use the top answer its far better

Comment: @rmx: No, the current top answer (provided by kappa) is worthless since it no longer supports partial matches.